# deactivate javascript import optimization for a single file in intellij

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, import

I was just following this tutorial on Angular 2 Google maps:
http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/

in which there exists the following import:

```
import { } from 'googlemaps';
```

Now my problem is that intellij recognizes this as an empty import and deletes it every time I reformat the file. I fixed it for now by deactivating the "optimize import"-option, which is kinda annoying because I'd like to use it in other files. So is there a way to ignore the formatting for a single file/single line of code? I tried

```
//@formatter:off    
import { } from 'googlemaps';
//@formatter:on
```

but intellij still keeps deleting the line on reformat. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26941 for updates.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the TypeScript compiler has a similar behaviour where unused imports are optimized away, and you can prevent it using the following syntax on an import:

```
// TypeScript compiler won't optimize this away
import 'googlemaps';
```

This prevents the compiler from removing what looks to be unused.

I am hoping that IntelliJ does a similar thing when you use this style.

Comment: I tried this as well, but then I get this compile error
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'googlemaps'`